# What happens when you call UItableview's reload twice

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

Imagine I have 200 rows in a tableView, what will happen if I call reload twice - meaning I have called reload on my tableview, while reloading the 100th row, I again call a reload, what happens now?

Comment: it will just show what your data source delivers - when you call reload your tableview will places the visible area to the beginning and ask your datasource for every visible cell again.

Comment: Imagine i have an heavy table view, there are twenty visible cells, in this state while the 10th cell is reloading, I call reload again, so will the remaining 10 alone be reloaded or the entire set of 20 will be?

Comment: I srsly doubt that you can pack so much into a tableview that still scrolls fluid that this would be an issue. and as rmaddy said, you can't reload the tableview during the reload anyway, since main thread ( where you would need to call the reload) is blocked anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question can't happen. All reloading is done on the main thread. The call to `reloadData` doesn't return until the reload is complete. So you can't call it a second time while the previous reload is still running. It's a non-issue.

And your question also implies a misunderstanding of how a table view is loaded. When you call `reloadData`, all 200 rows won't be "reloaded". The table view will re-determine the number and height of all rows and then it will only actually reload the visible rows. So there is no worry about "reloading the 100th row".

Comment: the question was more to understand the theory. Got the answer. Thanks

Comment: But will the second reload be executed after the first finishes. Supposing some other part of the code changes the datasource and now needs to reload the table whilst it is already reloading.. will the second reload request happen?